# I want to do a Inner join between two tables in the Django

Tags: python-2.7, django-models

I Have two tables, one of Treinamento(Training) and another of Entidade(Entity) and I'm really need to know how can I show the result of theses two models classes like a innerjoin between two models, anyone here can help me?

This is for a Windows 10 running in sqlite3 yet, localhost

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from phone_field import PhoneField
from datetime import time


# Create your models here.
class Entidade(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome_entidade = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    codigo_sap = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False)
    pessoa_contato = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=False, unique=True, error_messages={'required': 'Porfavor digite seu e-mail.', 'unique': 'Já existe esse e-mail cadastrado.'},)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Seu numero de telefone')
    cep = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,blank=False)
    endereço = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    data_registro = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_entidade




from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from phone_field import PhoneField
from localflavor.br.forms import BRZipCodeField
from datetime import time


Create your models here.

class Treinamento(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome_treinamento = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    conteudo =  models.TextField()
    requisito = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    recursos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    carga_horaria = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    local = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_treinamento
```

The Code are into different models and app.

I don't have any idea how I'll do it, or if this is possible.